# Passing value from table to another page in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table with data showed from the MySQL database.

Here is my controller:

```
function getData() {
        $data['data'] = DB::table('act_hi_procinst')->get();

        if(count($data) > 0) {
            return view('datatracking', $data);
        } else {
            return view('datatracking');
        }
}
```

Here is my view:

```
@foreach($data as $data)
    <tr>
        <td><a href= "{{ url('/') }}"> {{ $data -> ID_ }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ $data -> PROC_INST_ID_ }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data -> BUSINESS_KEY_ }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data -> PROC_DEF_ID_ }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data -> START_TIME_ }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data -> END_TIME_ }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data -> DURATION_ }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data -> START_USER_ID_ }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data -> START_ACT_ID_ }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data -> END_ACT_ID_ }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data -> SUPER_PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_ }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data -> DELETE_REASON_ }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data -> TENANT_ID_ }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data -> NAME_ }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I use `href` tag to make my first column into a link. I want when I click it, it will go to other page and passing the `ID_ value` to that page.
I have no idea how to write it in Laravel.

Comment: Perhaps `url.php?id=myID`? Then you could use $_GET

Comment: no it's not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it's value into URL and can get it through a query string

```
@foreach($data as $data)
     <tr>
         <td><a href= "{{ url('/') }}?id={{ $data -> ID_ }}"> {{ $data -> ID_ }}</a></td>
         <td>{{ $data -> PROC_INST_ID_ }}</td>
         <td>{{ $data -> BUSINESS_KEY_ }}</td>
         <td>{{ $data -> PROC_DEF_ID_ }}</td>
         <td>{{ $data -> START_TIME_ }}</td>
         <td>{{ $data -> END_TIME_ }}</td>
         <td>{{ $data -> DURATION_ }}</td>
         <td>{{ $data -> START_USER_ID_ }}</td>
         <td>{{ $data -> START_ACT_ID_ }}</td>
         <td>{{ $data -> END_ACT_ID_ }}</td>
         <td>{{ $data -> SUPER_PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_ }}</td>
         <td>{{ $data -> DELETE_REASON_ }}</td>
         <td>{{ $data -> TENANT_ID_ }}</td>
         <td>{{ $data -> NAME_ }}</td>
     </tr>
@endforeach
```

In your controller, you can get value like:

```
public function yourfuncName(Request $request)
{ 
    $id =  $request->get('id');
}
```

Comment: Can I use this line  $id =  $request->get('id'); in my controller function. Because I need to retrieve in controller first.

Comment: Yes it is for your controller section , check updated code

Comment: I receive this error : "Undefined variable: request"

Comment: Ok I fixed, I forgot put Request $request in my function, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Try this inside Your `forloop`

```
<td><a href="{{ url('/gotoPage/'.$data->ID_) }}">GoTo</a></td>
```

**And My Suggestion**

While iterating the array

> Correct Way

```
foreach ($data as $dataValue)
{
   $dataValue->id;
}
```

> WrongWay

```
foreach ($data as $data)
{
    $data->id;
}
```